# Is there a way to use QUICKFIX 1.14 if I don't have support for C++11?

Tags: c++11, boost, quickfix, fix-protocol

We are planning to use QUICKFIX 1.14, but most of our stuff is compiled using gcc 4.1 which does not support C++11.

While compiling QUICKFIX 1.14 I realised that it requires C++11 support (it uses std::shared_ptr).

What are my options here?

(Currently I am changing the std::shared_ptr usages to boost::shared_ptr)

Is there any other cleaner solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use QuickFIX 1.13.  It's probably the most widely-deployed version anyway.

Comment: Other than that, try using a version of GCC less than eight years old.  You can't expect a C++ compiler from 2007 to work with OSS from 2014.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I told my boss. In addition, I found that shared ptr is the only reason it fails. So just using boost shared ptr in all those places helped. Anyways, thanks